# How to Index Match an array in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My task is to find the text "Bend" in Column E thru H, then return the heading of that Column (Process 1, Process 2, ect..) or just return the column number. This would be in an Index function and dragged down 100 rows or so, only returning the column for the rows that contain "Bend".
So table Mat stores items and then has the Processes those items require.
[Mat table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8TJj.jpg)
Then table Bend column K finds the items that require the Bend process and retrieves the ID from Mat column A, the Bend table auto populates each row based on the retrieved ID's.
I need Bend column L to retrieve the column number or Process heading from table Mat for each row of table Bend.
[Bend table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd7Pj.jpg)
Trying to use Index with Match, but the Match doesn't like the array Mat!$E$4:$H$200

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Mat!$E$3:$H$3,,MATCH("BEND",Mat!$E$4:$H$200,0),ROW(1:1))," ")
```

Comment: I tried that, but it returns a value for every row in the Mat table, the rows that don't contain Bend return a blank cell. I need it to skip the rows that don't contain Bend.

Comment: Match returns a single numerical value where a criteria is matched in a row or column.  You cant have an array with rows and columns since that can't be represented with one number which is why it doesn't like $E$4:$H$200.

Comment: So can this be done with any other functions? Even if it takes multiple columns. Column K on the Bend table is already returning the ID field from the Mat table. Just need to know what column contains "Bend" for each ID in column K.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but have come up with this in cell G3 which you can edit as you wish, all you need to do is drag down...:

IFERROR(IF(MATCH("BEND",$B3:$B3,0)>0,$B$2,""),"")&" "&IFERROR(IF(MATCH("BEND",$C3:$C3,0)>0,$C$2,""),"")&" "&IFERROR(IF(MATCH("BEND",$D3:$D3,0)>0,$D$2,""),"")&" "&IFERROR(IF(MATCH("BEND",$E3:$E3,0)>0,$E$2,""),"")

[image]